how can i stop the Cell indicator from going out the borders?
here's a video of the problem
here's the scripts related to the grid system:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlacementSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject MouseIndicator,cellIndicator;
    [SerializeField] private InputManager inputManager;
    [SerializeField] private GridLayout grid;
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = inputManager.GetSelectesdMapPosition();
        Vector3Int gridPositon = grid.WorldToCell(mousePosition);
        MouseIndicator.transform.position = mousePosition;
        cellIndicator.transform.position = grid.CellToWorld(gridPositon);
        cellIndicator.transform.position += new Vector3(0f,.1f,0f);

    }
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private Camera sceneCamera;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask placementLayerMask;

    

    public Vector3 GetSelectesdMapPosition()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = sceneCamera.nearClipPlane;
        Ray ray = sceneCamera.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100, placementLayerMask))
        {
            lastPosition = hit.point;
        }

        return lastPosition;
    }
}


the problem is the cell indicator that's going out of the borders of the floor plane
i didn't find any thing about this problem in the internet so i didn't find any solution
the expected behaviour is the borders to be in the plane space and not get out the borders like in the video

you need to check the cell is valid for you to be indicating, the critieria you pick is dependant on what you decide makes it so

I guess first of all you should ensure that your room dimensions is actually a multiple of the grid size ... to me it looks like on the left and bottom edges in the video there is like half a cell within the room and the other half outside

@BugFinder sorry for the late reply but can you give me an over view on how to do this or any tutorial about this ?

@derHugo it isn't a multiple of the grid size , but even after i made it a multiple now the problem still the same ? sorry for the late reply btw

as derHugo has said, firstly it looks like your walls are in the middle of cells not edges, therefore if you allow selection of walls you're going to always have that, second, as I explained, if you dont want cells to be selectable, dont select them, mark them as either OK or not, choice is yours and dont allow the ones you dont want to be highlighted.. by checking.. with an if statement.

@BugFinder can you give me an example how can i make unselectable cells with the if statement ?

Im not writing it for you, you know how to use an if statement, just dont change the cellindicator positon if the cell is not one you have deemed valid

@BugFinder i''m not lazy to write bro i'm just a begginer making my first ever game, so i don't actually know how to do this i just asked how can i do it i didn't say do it for me

First. Not a bro. Second. You arent trying. So. Add as the 4th line of your placement update "if (gridPosition.x<0) return;" and see what that does. The rest is on you to adjust
